# Flexbox components have inconsistent spacing when using css gap property

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I am trying to set gutters for this custom button group arranged with `display: inline-flex`, but when I set the `gap` property of this group to 2px, there is some inconsistency in the gap between the buttons.

This seems like a browser issue when it is approximating sizing of fractional-width buttons (which resize to the size of the text within), as sometimes the gap discrepancy appears between different buttons, not only affecting the last one as shown in the attached pictures below.

Is there a way to ensure visually consistent gaps between divs? The issue is subtle but noticeable. I have zoomed in the attached picture to make it more clear what is going on.

```
// Make the div behave like a button
.custom-btn-group {

    @include font-defaults;

    display: inline-flex;

    // Force the buttons to adopt the overall group radius
    border-radius: $custom-button-group-border-radius;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: $custom-button-shadow;
    gap: 2px;

    > .custom-btn {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        // Turn off the normal button radius and shadow that's now on the group
        border-radius: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```

[zoomed in group of buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxcpn.png) 
[2nd group of buttons with different gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22kmj.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: where is the HTML ? inline-boxes treat spaces around as white-space, so if you have a few inline-flex boxes side by side, white-space from the code are also rendered. clarify your question adding all the code necessary to reproduce your issue ;) ... it, probably, is not a flex issue.

Comment: I am using typescript+react for HTML.
You seem to be right that it's not a flex problem, but instead related to fractional pixel widths of the buttons rounding to the nearest whole number.
Any idea how to fix that?